# How to find out where my IP address is sent

Tags: ip-address, developer-tools

How can I find out where my IP address is sent once I visite a website?

Lets say I visite example.com and that site has a facebook-share button. After entering the site my ip-address is sent to facebook. That is a fact more or less everybody knows. But how can I track other receivers of my ip address?

I heard, that that it is quite easy to find out by using the developer tools of the browser. Unfortunately I could not find any information about that topic in the web. I would be glad if anybody could help me with further information.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome, open Tools / Developer Tools, then the Network tab. Reload the page. The tab will show all requests made by the browser to different domains.

Comment: Thank you, i did it with this site here. The result is a very long list.  Most parts of the list are made up from data that is from https://stackoverflow.com. That I would like to filter out. 

I am only interested in third party-domains that receive my IP. So maybe Google oder Facebook. 

Is there a way of showing only these domains, but nothing else?

Thanks